# How to get post values in a array from form created using loop in codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, for-loop

I need to get post value as array from form created using for loop ,

Here is my view

```
   <?php for ($i=0;$i<5;$i++) {?>
            <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Name</label>
                    <input name="<?php echo 'fname'.$i?>" class="form-control" type="text" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Surname</label>
                    <input  name="<?php echo 'sname'.$i?>" class="form-control" type="text" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Date of Birth</label>
                    <input name="<?php echo 'dob'.$i?>" class="date-pick-years form-control" type="text" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <?php }?>

        <input type="submit" />
```

How to get these post value in controller , i need as a array for example i value is 2 means i need my output as

```
    $array1=array('name'=>$this->input->post('name0')),'sname'=>$this->input->post('sname0')),'dob'=>$this->input->post('dob0'))

   $array2=array('name'=>$this->input->post('name1')),'sname'=>$this->input->post('sname1')),'dob'=>$this->input->post('dob1'))

Total array =array($array1,$array2);
```

How to get this in a loop in controller to get required output

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get an array of values that belong semantically to the same `name` value, use `[]` in your html:

```
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Name</label>
            <input name="fname[<?=$i?>]" class="form-control" type="text" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

Then use the usual `$data = $this->input->post()` in your controller to read out the data. The data should be in this format:

```
$post[
       fname [
           0 => 'name1',
           1 => 'name2',
           ...
       ],
       sname [
           0 => 'sname1',
           1 => 'sname2',
           ...
       ],
       ...
   ]
]
```

### Update: Format this into the format you want

```
$resultArray = array();
for($i = 0; $i < <formlength>; $i++) {
    $resultArray[$i]['fname'] = $post['fname'][$i];
    $resultArray[$i]['sname'] = $post['sname'][$i];
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks but i need as first form fields in 1st array 2nd form fields in 2nd array like that it should be

Comment: Ok so with this you should be able to do this, it's really easy. Ill update my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) { ?>
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Name</label>
                <input name="data[item<?php echo $i; ?>][<?php echo 'fname' . $i ?>]" class="form-control" type="text"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Surname</label>
                <input name="data[item<?php echo $i; ?>][<?php echo 'sname' . $i ?>]" class="form-control" type="text"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Date of Birth</label>
                <input name="data[item<?php echo $i; ?>][<?php echo 'dob' . $i ?>]" class="date-pick-years form-control" type="text"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<?php } ?>
```

You will get:

```
$_POST['data'] = array (
    'item0' =>
        array (
            'fname0' => '',
            'sname0' => '',
            'dob0' => '',
        ),
    'item1' =>
        array (
            'fname1' => '',
            'sname1' => '',
            'dob1' => '',
        ),
    'item2' =>
        array (
            'fname2' => '',
            'sname2' => '',
            'dob2' => '',
        ),
    'item3' =>
        array (
            'fname3' => '',
            'sname3' => '',
            'dob3' => '',
        ),
    'item4' =>
        array (
            'fname4' => '',
            'sname4' => '',
            'dob4' => '',
        ),
);
```

If you want to use them in variables you can extract it:

```
$data = $this->input->post('data');
if(is_array($data)) {
    extract($data);
    if(isset($item1)) {
        var_export($item1);
// it will contains:
//        array (
//            'fname1' => '',
//            'sname1' => '',
//            'dob1' => '',
//        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code in your html code than you get the right result as per your requirement.

```
<?php for ($i=0;$i<5;$i++) {?>
                <div class="row">

                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Name</label>
                        <input name="name[<?=$i?>][fname]" class="form-control" type="text" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Surname</label>
                        <input  name="name[<?=$i?>][sname]" class="form-control" type="text" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Date of Birth</label>
                        <input name="name[<?=$i?>][dob]" class="date-pick-years form-control" type="text" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <?php }?>

            <input type="submit" />
```